# How to increment a number on button click?

Tags: java, android

In my app i have a form which the user clicks on "add" and then it the user would fill in the form.  (The form is the same every time the user selects "add"

What i would like to achieve is to have a "job number" that increases every time a new form is created.

I can't get this to work and tried almost every solution that I could find here and in google.

Here is my code I have:

This in my CreateOrEditForm.java class

```
EditText jobnumberEditText;

String newKey;
int code = 0;
.....

jobnumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextJobnumber);
    if(code <= 0){
        code = 1;
    }else{
        code++;
    }
    newKey = "000" + code;
    jobnumberEditText.setText("000" + code);
```

and in my MainForm.java class

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(JobCardMainActivity.this, CreateOrEditJobCards.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID, 0);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

What is happening now is that when the user clicks on add the number does not increase and stays at 1

Could someone please assist?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The app contains a list view of the various forms created and underneath contains the "add" button

```
 jobnumberEditText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("counter"));
```

And in previous class:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(JobCardMainActivity.this, CreateOrEditJobCards.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID, 0);
            count++;
            intent.putExtra("counter", count);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

**EDIT 2**

I have found a solution to get it to increment, but when I tap on the form in list view to delete it counts that as well.  So for example when I tap "add" to create form it gives me a number of 0001 I then save the form.  When I go into that form to delete it and create a new for the number will then be 0003 istead of 0002.

Please see code below:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key_code", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int code = sp.getInt("code",0);

    if(code <= 0){
        code = 1;
    }else{
        code++;
    }
    sp.edit().putInt("code",code).commit();
    newKey = "000" + code;

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(JobCardMainActivity.this, CreateOrEditJobCards.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID, 0);
            intent.putExtra("000",newKey);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Then in my other class:

```
jobnumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextJobnumber);
    jobnumberEditText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("000"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment the number always when user click the button so move the code inside listener otherwise , `code` will be incremented once in `oncreate` and stays the same

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            incrementCountAndDisplay();
            Intent intent = new Intent(JobCardMainActivity.this, CreateOrEditJobCards.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID, 0);
            //intent.putExtra("counter", newKey);
            intent.putExtra("counter", String.ValueOf(count));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

// separate function for code clarity
void incrementCountAndDisplay(){
     code++;
     newKey = "000" + code;
     jobnumberEditText.setText(newKey); // use newKey
}
```

Edit : you need to send a `String` instead of `int` with `counter` key so use `String.ValueOf(count)` while putting data in `intent` or you can fetch an `int` using `getIntExtra` but eventually you need a string so pass a string

Comment: Hi, its not working.  I have found a sort-of-solution.  Please see edited question.  Thanks

Comment: @Newbie it should be working with your `Edit` although not in your expected way because you posted a question to increment and display `count` dear not to save it across app restarts , `1 tip` move your save preference code in `onStop` you don't need to do it on every click

Comment: thanks, but I am not quite following what you are saying?

Comment: How would i go about doing that as you suggested?

Comment: @Newbie see `How to increment a number on button click?` my solution is to this issue but clearly seems like from your solution , you don't want to increment `count` on every button click but if you want then you can use suggested solution with `sharedpreference`

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
int count =0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(JobCardMainActivity.this, CreateOrEditJobCards.class);
        count++;
        intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID, count);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

And when you recieve this data:

```
EditText jobnumberEditText;


String newKey;
// you can also use your already defined intent 
int code = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRA_CONTACT_ID);
.....

jobnumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextJobnumber);
newKey = "000" + code;
jobnumberEditText.setText("000" + code);
```

Comment: Thanks,  but it is not showing the number now in my edittext field,  Please see updated question.